# Orientability of Complex Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, grassmannian

I have seen a statement that complex Grassmannian of any dimension is orientable, while real Grassmannian is orientable iff it is even-dimensional. Is there a way to prove it using elementary means (e.g. not using anything more than e.g. calculations in charts, or perhaps determinant of some sort, etc.)?

There is a way to do so for real and projective spaces, which requires us to simply look at standard atlases. I am wondering if there is something similar for Grassmannian.

Comment: Do you know that the complex grassmannians are complex manifolds? If so, it follows from the fact that complex manifolds are orientable.

Comment: Yes I do @MichaelAlbanese but because I have no formal knowledge on complex manifolds I would need to know the whole complex manifold in general. Hence I wonder if there is a specific way to find it instead of that.

Comment: What do you mean by a real Grassmannian being orientable iff it is even-dimensional? $G(1,3) \cong \Bbb RP^2$ is hardly orientable. Same holds for $G(2,3)$. So what exactly is supposed to be even?